# A recently deployed field shows up on objects, but is not available when executing in "Execute Anonymous Window"

Tags: execute-anonymous

I get this pretty standard error:

Line: 1, Column: 25
No such column 'card_version__c' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

It's as if the field does not exist, but when I go to a given account and see if the field has gone through, it is there. Does it take a while to *really* go through, or is there something I need to do before using it?

Comment: Did you ensure that your profile has permission to the field?

Comment: Ah, good thinking. I assumed that since I'm an admin, it would automatically allow me. I went to Field Accessibility and it is hidden for all. I don't remember where to change this. Perhaps worth noting that what I did in the sandbox worked, without changing permissions or anything.

Comment: Oops! Was logged in as another user. I found where to edit accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the field in a Sandbox, you are prompted during the process to assign field-level security by profile. When you deploy that field via change set, unless you also deploy Profiles, no profiles will have access.

That said, it's sometimes dicey to deploy profiles - they could overwrite other changes you made in production since the SB refresh, or you may have opened up the profiles in SB to accommodate development and testing. For a field or two, it can often be simpler to just manage the FLS in production post-deploy.

Comment: The change set will only change the aspects of the profile that touch included components. Fields, objects, pages, etc. Not wholesale.

Comment: Well,  except that the parts of the profile that aren't tied to another specific piece of metadata, like system permissions, come along for the ride in any case. See this answer from earlier today: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/146060/3934